# Is there any method for finding the root of a polynomial of any degree that is less "trial and error" than the Rational/Irrational Root Theorems?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

In Algebra II, we familiarize ourselves with the Rational/Irrational Root Theorems. These are fine for high school homework, but start adding more terms and the problem of finding the roots just gets more difficult, since you now have more terms to divide by each possible root.

Comment: Please make your question specific and clear.

Comment: "Start adding more terms and the problem of finding the roots just gets more difficult" is the understatement of the century.

Comment: There's something called [Newton's Method.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method)